# Python function which takes information from two lists to return information from a third list

Tags: python, list

I have the information for all 3 lists.

- list `w` would be the possible width dimensions of an object
- list `h` would be the possible height dimensions of an object
- list `p` would be the specific pricing when any 1 width and 1 height is chosen from each respective list to give a defined result from list p

Since there are 9 possible combinations of w with h, I have defined 9 prices, one for each combination.

**EDIT: Here is how it all interacts
[Here is the price chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVE7v.jpg)**

Here are the lists which I want to interact, I am completely stumped:

```
w = [59.5, 71.5, 95.5]
h = [79.5, 81.5, 95.5]
p = [880.00, 895.00, 945.00, 960.00, 980.00, 1045.00, 1120.00, 1135.00, 1225.00]
```

Comment: So, which of the 9 prices corresponds to which if the 3x3 combinations? Also, is there any chance you can still change the format?

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: Get the index of the width and height, then use `w_index * 3 + h_index` as the index into `p`.

Comment: What do you actually want to achieve? Generate list `p` from `w` and `h`? Get the right element from `p` given two _elements_ from `w` and `h`? Something entirely different?

Comment: But I agree with @tobias_k that it would be better to change the data structure. A dictionary that maps tuples to prices would be better.

Comment: @tobias_k The title says he wants to return information from the third list, not generate the list.

Comment: Yes I can change the format, not problem @tobias_k and ill make a note of which width and which height corresponds with which price.

Comment: I agree with @barmar, in theory, howver if you are doing more than a quick & dirty app, and you have more than 9 combinations OR the prices change frequently, you would need a different approach using a database or external source, so you don't have to change the code if data change.

Comment: @user3758232 its a project I am working on for which I have all the data already, its just all about practicality. The goal is to create eventually create a basic quoting app for our product which can be used on site by a project manager to give a customer a general price.

Comment: Consider using pandas to organize the data into a table.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, since we don't exactly understand the relationship between the price & length & width, you will have to manually enter in the price as below - build a dictionary of tuples:

```
w = [59.5, 71.5, 95.5]
h = [79.5, 81.5, 95.5]
p = [880.00, 895.00, 945.00, 960.00, 980.00, 1045.00, 1120.00, 1135.00, 1225.00]

d = dict()
# width = one of the values in w list
# height = one of the values in h list
d[(width, height)] = ... # one of the values in p list
```

Once you complete this, you can do something like the below to easily obtain the price.

```
d[(width, height)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear. By 'interact' i think you mean the data needs to be structured as in the screenshot you have shared.

You can use a pandas dataframe to structure and numpy for reshaping p

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame(np.array(p).reshape((3,-1)),columns=w,index=h)
```

```
          59.5    71.5    95.5
79.5     880.0   895.0   945.0
81.5     960.0   980.0  1045.0
95.5    1120.0  1135.0  1225.0
```